# Best free Baskerville font with small caps

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec, small-caps

I have been using the Baskervald font for a document but have realised that small caps do not work with it. Instead lowercase letters are used. Is there a better free option if you want these features or is there a way to somehow use LaTeX to reduce the normal caps to small caps (although that might not look correct)?

I've looked around the net for other free clones but most are limited in similar ways.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unfortunately, I only know of [Open Baskerville](http://klepas.org/openbaskerville/) and it doesn't have small caps. That said, since it is open-source, you can easily create small caps from capitals using fontforge:

- Open the otf file with fontforge ;
- Select all capital letters ;
- Go to Element -> Style -> Add small capitals
- Generate a new OTF file (File -> Generate fonts).

You can then use it with `fontspec`:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{fontspec,xunicode}
\setmainfont{OpenBaskerville0.0.53}

\begin{document}

This is a text in \textsc{Open Baskerville} using \textsc{Small Caps}.

\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image: Open Baskerville with small caps]

Comment: +1 Would these be considered "faked" small capitals? The uppercase letters appear to have more weight.

Comment: They're considered "small caps from caps" (`c2sc` OTF feature, as opposed to the `smcp` feature). The fontforge dialog allows you to refine them as you create them. Real small caps are usually refined manually after their conversion.